# What is the scope of (nested) autorelease pools?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management, autorelease

I'm creating an autorelease pool in a for loop (in method A). At each iteration of the loop, I'm calling another method (method B). Method B returns an autoreleased object to Method A. If I drain the pool within the for loop in Method A, will that release the objects sent from Method B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - any time an object is sent `-autorelease`, it's added to the highest level autorelease pool.  As long as you aren't creating any new autorelease pools in method B or further down the call stack, method A's pool should be the highest level pool.

Comment: The only catch is threads — autorelease pool stacks are per-thread.